# autoexpect script.exp

Tags: bash, expect

I use autoexpect generated a script.exp. see following.

how to understand

expect -exact " \r
Type ha for help on aliases\r
 \r
]0;luoric@linux-pc-64:/home/luoric/tmp[01;34mluoric@linux-pc-64[01;34m tmp \$[00m " ?

and after I run script.exp. I got "ls" and "ls -l" result correctly.
and get command line prompt. but when I hit enter. there is no command line prompt. I have to use ctrl C, to exit so I can continue enter command from terminal.

What I'm missing?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#
# This Expect script was generated by autoexpect on Tue Dec 18 09:42:08 2018
# Expect and autoexpect were both written by Don Libes, NIST.
#
# Note that autoexpect does not guarantee a working script.  It
# necessarily has to guess about certain things.  Two reasons a script
# might fail are:
#
# 1) timing - A surprising number of programs (rn, ksh, zsh, telnet,
# etc.) and devices discard or ignore keystrokes that arrive "too
# quickly" after prompts.  If you find your new script hanging up at
# one spot, try adding a short sleep just before the previous send.
# Setting "force_conservative" to 1 (see below) makes Expect do this
# automatically - pausing briefly before sending each character.  This
# pacifies every program I know of.  The -c flag makes the script do
# this in the first place.  The -C flag allows you to define a
# character to toggle this mode off and on.

set force_conservative 0  ;# set to 1 to force conservative mode even if
              ;# script wasn't run conservatively originally
if {$force_conservative} {
    set send_slow {1 .1}
    proc send {ignore arg} {
        sleep .1
        exp_send -s -- $arg
    }
}

#
# 2) differing output - Some programs produce different output each time
# they run.  The "date" command is an obvious example.  Another is
# ftp, if it produces throughput statistics at the end of a file
# transfer.  If this causes a problem, delete these patterns or replace
# them with wildcards.  An alternative is to use the -p flag (for
# "prompt") which makes Expect only look for the last line of output
# (i.e., the prompt).  The -P flag allows you to define a character to
# toggle this mode off and on.
#
# Read the man page for more info.
#
# -Don


set timeout -1
spawn $env(SHELL)
match_max 100000
expect -exact " \r
Type ha for help on aliases\r
 \r
\]0;luoric@linux-pc-64:/home/luoric/tmp\[01;34mluoric@linux-pc-64\[01;34m tmp \$\[00m "
send -- "ls\r"
expect -exact "ls\r
\[0m\[00;32manswerbot\[0m  \[00;32mexecmds.sh\[0m  \[00;32mexecmds.sh.exp\[0m  \[00;32mgdb.sh\[0m  \[00min\[0m  \[00mnohup.out\[0m  \[00;32mquestions\[0m  \[00;32mscript.exp\[0m  \[00mspawn\[0m  \[00;32mstb.sh\[0m  \[00;32mtarget.exp\[0m  \[00;32mtarget.sh\[0m  \[00;32mtel\[0m  \[00mtel.log\[0m  \[00;32mterm\[0m\r
\]0;luoric@linux-pc-64:/home/luoric/tmp\[01;34mluoric@linux-pc-64\[01;34m tmp \$\[00m "
send -- "ls -l\r"
expect -exact "ls -l\r
total 56\r
-rwxrwxr-x 1 luoric ccuser  256 Dec 10 14:26 \[0m\[00;32manswerbot\[0m\r
-rwxrwxr-x 1 luoric ccuser  264 Dec 13 17:07 \[00;32mexecmds.sh\[0m\r
-rwxrwxr-x 1 luoric ccuser  424 Dec 13 17:13 \[00;32mexecmds.sh.exp\[0m\r
-rwxrwxr-x 1 luoric ccuser  118 Dec 17 13:44 \[00;32mgdb.sh\[0m\r
-rw-rw-r-- 1 luoric ccuser    8 Dec 10 12:13 \[00min\[0m\r
-rw------- 1 luoric ccuser 6920 Dec 14 15:35 \[00mnohup.out\[0m\r
-rwxrwxr-x 1 luoric ccuser  160 Dec 10 14:30 \[00;32mquestions\[0m\r
-rwxrwxr-x 1 luoric ccuser    0 Dec 18 09:42 \[00;32mscript.exp\[0m\r
-rw-rw-r-- 1 luoric ccuser    0 Dec 13 12:56 \[00mspawn\[0m\r
-rwxrwxr-x 1 luoric ccuser  103 Dec 10 14:41 \[00;32mstb.sh\[0m\r
-rwxrwxr-x 1 luoric ccuser  463 Dec 17 14:57 \[00;32mtarget.exp\[0m\r
-rwxrwxr-x 1 luoric ccuser  140 Dec 17 13:50 \[00;32mtarget.sh\[0m\r
-rwxrwxr-x 1 luoric ccuser  864 Dec 17 11:46 \[00;32mtel\[0m\r
-rw-rw-r-- 1 luoric ccuser 1201 Dec 11 14:03 \[00mtel.log\[0m\r
-rwxrwxr-x 1 luoric ccuser  153 Dec 13 13:13 \[00;32mterm\[0m\r
\]0;luoric@linux-pc-64:/home/luoric/tmp\[01;34mluoric@linux-pc-64\[01;34m tmp \$\[00m "
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: Don't use `autoexpect` unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Autoexpect records **exactly** what you typed, and **exactly** what you saw. You saw colourized text thanks to your shell profile's `ls` alias, and autoexpect dutifully wrote the terminal colour codes into the file. When I use autoexpect, I always immediately edit the resulting script and remove probably 95% of the contents -- you generally just want to determine what the prompts are so you can use them as the `expect` patterns.

Answer (score 1):

As a (formatted) followup to my comment, this is the actual take-away from that autoexpect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set prompt "\$\[00m $"
spawn bash
expect -re $prompt
send -- "ls\r"
expect -re $prompt
send -- "ls -l\r"
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
```

That's what I mean about removing 95%.

---

To actually answer your question, if you want to interact with the spawned shell, change

```
expect eof
```

to

```
interact
```

That stops the scripted interaction and puts the user in command.